# wordpress: plugin updates not updating

Tags: wordpress, plugins

To be clear on some things, I have tried:

- going into config.php and inputting define FS_Method, FTP_Base, FTP_Content_Dir, FTP_Plugin_Dir, FTP_User, FTP_Pass, FTP_Host, FTP_SSL
- setting file permissions to 755 on wp-content, wp-content/uploads, wp-content/plugins

Things I do **not** have access to: cpanel, file manager, ubuntu, commands, SSH credentials.

I have spoken to my web host (it is a shared host account), and they will not provide me info on SSH. The only backend I have access to is wordpress admin and FTP through FileZilla or WinSCP. The web host has declared this issue to be in my court and refuses to help me out (unless I want to be charged a hefty fee).

Now, the issue is updating plugins. I can activate and deactivate plugins. But I can't install, delete or update plugins. Originally, the issue was "can't create directory" but then I changed define(FS_METHOD) to ftpsockets. Originally it was direct. (ftpext did not work whatsoever).

NOW the issue is "Update Failed: Could not copy file. all-in-one-wp-migration/all-in-one-wp-migration.php" for the plugin All-in-one WP Migration.

Can anyone help me out or point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

check your disk quota , the space assigned to your account , it looks like you may be overquota and hence the updates are failed.

Answer (score 0):

As other posts indicate, the root cause is a permissions problem in /var/www/html/wordpress. In my case, I used Microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-lamp-stack to install LAMP in Azure on Ubuntu 18.x LTS. I set the app to use the SFTP plugin for updates & uploads per https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/. Then I changed permissions in as needed to the directories 'plugins themes upgrade uploads', group www-data (I used top to determine this, but other tools will do the trick), 775 on directories and 664 on files. Of course the user ID used to SFTP files had to be added to the www-data group on the system. I DID NOT set permissions to 777 as some have suggested in other posts and blogs.

Your situation may vary for required group ownership permissions. So analyze accordingly.

And best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Get your webhost to do this or you can do it yourself if you have SSH access

sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www

you may want to revert back to the default: prevent writeable
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www